# jquery dropdown stays open till complete page load

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have markup like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Courses</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href='whatever'>A Level</a></li>
    <li><a href='whatever'>Arts</a></li>
    <li><a href='whatever'>Commerce</a></li>
    <li><a href='whatever'>I.B.</a></li>
    <li><a href='whatever'>Science</a></li>
    </ul>

</li>
<li><a href="/college/collegeFinder">Find A College</a></li>
<li><a href="/college">College Reviews</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

and the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
mainmenu();
$('#slider1').bxSlider({
    autoHover: true,
    auto: true,
    pause: 7000,
    prevImage: 'images/upleft.png',
    nextImage: 'images/upright.png'
});

function mainmenu(){
    $(" .dropdown ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
    $(" .dropdown li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(200);
        },function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').slideUp(200);
    });
}
});
```

edit: (ignore the bxslider part)

Im not very good with jquery and just picked this script off from some tutorial. Basically, while the page is loading, the dropdown is open, up until the rest of the page loads. It's only for a second or 2 but its really annoying.
It can be seen here: passout.co.in 
Any ideas ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UDcYD/7/ its working fine?? what is the problem

Comment: soul, I think thats beacuse there isnt much to render. Anyway, its fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add CSS rules for ul.dropdown to display:none or opacity:0, which ever is better suited. That way, on page load, it remains hidden until your jQuery is activated.

Cheers!

Comment: I also had to add $('.dropdown li').css({opacity:1}); to the jQuery apart from changing opacity to 0 in the CSS. But yeah, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it to be hidden by default with CSS:

```css
ul.dropdown li 
{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its called [FOUC](http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/) (Flash Of Unstyled Content) and It can be avoided by hiding the stuff which you want to show or applying the styling or event bubbling using jquery. So write some css class which can hide the dropdown on page load.